# Saving/Updating multiple different entities on datastore with ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am optimizing our app engine backend RPC calls and I noticed below lines:

```
ndb.put_multi(list_of_emails)
ndb.put_multi(list_of_events)
ndb.put_multi(list_of_stats)
```

So I thought why not just do this instead:

```
ndb.put(list_of_emails + list_of_events + list_of_stats)
```

From multiple ndb.put_multi() calls down to  a single call.

Although this works fine from my testing. Question: Is this a good idea to put different entities/models in a single ndb.put_multi() call?

The docs [ndb.put_multi()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions#put_multi) says "it stores a sequence of Model instances." but how about a sequence of different model instances?

Answer (score 0):

I've never had any problems passing a collection of different types of entity to `ndb.put_multi`, so I believe this is fine.  However like you, I don't see anything that explicitly confirms this in the documentation.